# Авторизация на стороннем сайте с последующим чтением страницы этого сайта?

Tags: скрипт, php, авторизация

Есть некий сайт, доступ к страницам которого возможен после авторизации пользователя.
Соответственно, есть пользователь, который зарегистрирован на этом сайте с правами чтения необходимых страниц.
Как из php-скрипта выполнить авторизацию на этом сайте под заданным пользователем (логин и пароль, естественно, известны) и прочитать необходимые страницы с этого сайта?
Что будет, если такую операцию попытаются выполнить одновременно несколько станций?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> Что будет, если такую операцию
> попытаются выполнить одновременно
> несколько станций?

ничего не будет, по крайней мере обычно)

изучите как там авторизация проходит, какие пути/файлы/скрипты задействованы, а потом почитайте про [curl, авторизация на сайте](http://xdan.ru/avtorizacija-na-sajte-pri-pomoshhi-curl-php.html) к примеру либо в гугль ;)

Answer (score 1):

Почитай про HTTP заголовки. Сайт-сервер вернёт тебе Cookies, которые ты должен будешь отправлять в заголовке каждого запроса при чтении страниц.

- Что будет, если такую операцию попытаются выполнить одновременно несколько станций?

Это зависит от настроек того сайта. Может заблокировать доступ остальным клиентам. Придётся переавторизовываться.

Answer (score 0):

[Guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/fabpot/goutte) Вам в помощь:

Cтавим через composer : `composer require fabpot/goutte`

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

$jar = new CookieJar();

/** @var Client $client **/
$client = new Client([ 'cookies' => $jar ]);

/** Получаем первую страницу и пишем куку **/
$page = $client->get('http://localhost/login');

/** Проводим авторизацию по полям login + password  **/
$page = $client->post('http://localhost/login', [
    'form_params' => [
        'login' => 'demo',
        'password' => 'something'
    ]
]);

// $page->getBody()->getContents() Вернет страницу целиком
```